# Is it possible to transfrom a transfer function into voltage?

Tags: control, matlab, transfer-function

So I have a control system which I'd like to control externally. I have the error signal from the system and I use an ADC to convert the signal to number. I have the transfer function of the system (calculated with CHR method). I want to use a PI (Proportional- Integral control). And I have a DAC to convert a signal back to an analog signal.
But now, I only have a transfer function: $$11.3 s^2 + 5.82 s$$
So how can I feed back this signal to the system?

Comment: This transfer function looks a bit "weird". Are you sure about it? More than that: You speak about "this signal". Which signal? A function is not a signal!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your controller must be implemented digitally in discrete time, you have two options :

1. Design your PI controller in the continuous time (s) domain and
   convert to discrete time.
2. Convert your plant to discrete time and design the PI controller
   accordingly.

Method (2) is generally preferred because it handles delays more easily and the controller is directly implementable without additional transforms. Look at [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144045/why-do-we-use-this-particular-approximation-for-the-bilinear-transform/144123#144123) for more info.

Once you have the controller in discrete time make sure it's in polynomial form:
$$\dfrac{Y(z^{-1})}{X(z^{-1})}=\dfrac{b_0+b_1z^{-1}+..+b_kz^{-k}}{1+a_1z^{-1}+..+a_kz^{-k}}$$

and convert to a difference equation that can be directly implemented in hardware:

$$b_0x(n)+b_1x(n-1)+..+b_kx(n-k)=y(n)+a_1y(n-1)+a_2y(n-2)+..a_ky(n-k)$$